# htaccess rewrite for wildcard subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

few hours later, i need help. I trie to rewrite the url for using wildcard subdomains.

My domains will be *.domain.com - for example mytest.domain.com

For every subdomain is a subfolder unter www.domain.com/sdom/content/mytest

I've setup the apache/nginx server. For testing i upload a index.html inside the "content" folder.

If i type mytest.comain.com this index.html will display. So now i upload the .htaccess file inside this folder to route from here to the destinations (in this example to the "mytest" folder).

I trie a lot of thiks, at least this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /httpdocs/domain/sdom/content/$1/index.html
```

i call mytest.domain.com but it wont go to the subfolder, it go to the maindomain.

If i delete the htaccess file, the index.html of the "content" folder will display.

After rewriting the url in the adressfield of the browser shoul display mytest.domain.com - not the new path to the subfolder etc.

What i have to do, that is works ?

UPDATE

subdomains route to -> mainfolder
subdomains should route by htaccess to folder that has the same name of the subdomain

So i trie htacess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^$ /subdomainfolder/index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `.htaccess` files you can't. Here `mytest.domain.com` and `www.domain.com` are different hostnames. So inevitably an external redirect will happen.

If you want different domains run by one physical server you should use virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> # Change this to *:443 if you use SSL/TLS
    ServerName mytest.domain.com # Your domain name
    DocumentRoot $SRV_ROOT/httpdocs/domain/sdom/content/mytest/ # assuming $SRV_ROOT is set to root of your server
    <Directory "$SRV_ROOT/httpdocs/domain/sdom/content/mytest/">
        Require all granted # on Apache 2.4
        # Below are instructions for Apache 2.2
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need to restart your server each time you add a subdomain, as well as having a DNS record or local record in `/etc/hosts` file if you test locally.

Comment: maybe ignor the www. part i think its not that i need, for me only the part of the subdomains and routing to another folder is the important think

Comment: Even domain.com and mytest.domain.com are different domain names according to Apache. Also when you use relative URLs, they are relative to the document root of the current virtual host, not relative to the server root.

Comment: im sorry, my head is on fire - maybe i must start from new. How i can split the {mytest}.domain.com wich ist route to subdomain folder to another folder without seeing that in the adressfield of the browser?

Comment: Are you putting the subdomain folder into the main domain folder?

Comment: its not fixe, i can change it, i try both, but both ways failed for me

Comment: Apache must make a redirect to your subdomain folder, so the true URL (namely domain.com/domain/sdom/content/mytest/index.html) will be shown in the address bar.

Comment: is there no other way?

Comment: There is unfortunately no other way than virtual hosts to manage multiple domains on a single physical server, and make them visible to the client (the web browser) - virtual hosts are more flexible than subdomain —> main domain subfolder mapping. Or you would rather use your host provider's tools to make the task easier?

Comment: only for sure, If i want NO different domains (only the subdomains) run by one physical server is there a way :-) ?

Comment: Yes, through virtual hosts you can setup your physical server to host multiple subdomains at a time! Remember that you must restart the server each time you add a subdomain to host.

Comment: last try :-) Is it possible with htaccess to rewrite dynamically from subdomain.maindomain.com to subdomain.maindomain.com/subdomain and after that hide the subdomain folder in url?

Comment: This is possible as these URLs have the same domain name. Using rewrite rules you can hide the path (i.e. /subdomain) part in the URL shown to browsers, even in .htaccess files! Just ensure that Options FollowSymLinks is present in httpd.conf, and that RewriteEngine on is in your .htaccess file.

Comment: ok, i've update my code, i only need to know how i can fetch the subdomain part and use it instead the 'subdomainfolder' - coulde you help me at this?

Comment: Yes, using back references : `RewriteCond ^([^.]*)\.domain\.com` will extract the subdomain part - if you're using mytest.example.test, you'll receive "mytest"). In RewriteRules you can use back references to refer to the captured string; for the condition above, the subdomain part will be `%1`. Resulting rewrite rule would be `RewriteRule (.*) /%1$1` ($1 is the reference to request URI).

Comment: top, one step ahead. What i have to write in rewriterule, if i want to rewrite only to the subdomainfolder(%1) and the part after the domain (i mean files and other folders) for example subodomain/myfile.html

Comment: You'll have to use the `%{REQUEST_URI}` environment variable. If you placed the `RewriteRule` directive in the virtual host block then you don't have to worry about that, the matched pattern (`$1`) already contains the full URL path (for example /myfile.html, if you captured the URL path using `(.*)` in the RewriteRule).

Comment: Oops, remember to replace `RewriteCond (^[^.]*)\.domain.com` with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^[^.]*)\.domain.com`!